# Syntax issue in finding the textbox controls used in a GridViews emptytemplate control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to insert data into an xml file via an **emptydatatemplate control** that consist of two textbox controls and a link control:

...the design:

```
<emptydatatemplate>
 No Data Found. <br /> 
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAltprodID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAltprodNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkpro" runat="server" OnClick="writeProductInfo" Text="Add Product Number"></asp:LinkButton>
</emptydatatemplate>
```

The input submitted by the textbox control are to be placed within the product table of the following XML file:

```
<PersonalData>
  <products>
    <product>
      <productID>2</productID>
      <productNumber>123744</productNumber>
    </product>
    <product>
      <productID>7</productID>
      <productNumber>123456</productNumber>
    </product>
  </products>
  <customers>
    <customer>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
      <Address>1234 Crescent RD</Address>
      <City>San Antonio</City>
      <State>Texas</State>
      <ZipCode>67894</ZipCode>
    </customer>
  </customers>
</PersonalData>
```

I Created the following event handler for the Add Product info link:

```
Public Sub writeProductInfo(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim altprodID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.EmptyDataTemplate.FindControl("txtAltprodID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim altprodNum As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.EmptyDataTemplate.FindControl("txtAltprodNum"), TextBox).Text
        BindGridView()
        Dim oDs As DataSet = gvProductNumber.DataSource
        Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables(0).NewRow
        oDr("productID") = altprodID
        oDr("productNumber") = altprodNum
        oDs.Tables(0).Rows.Add(oDr)
        oDs.WriteXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml")
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
```

...however, there is an issue in my syntax:

```
Dim altprodID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.EmptyDataTemplate.FindControl("txtAltprodID"), TextBox).Text
            Dim altprodNum As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.EmptyDataTemplate.FindControl("txtAltprodNum"), TextBox).Text
```

...could I get some help in how I'm to go about in setting up the two lines above to read the ID's of the textbox controls from the emptydatatemplate? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you will get the ID's:

```
 Public Sub writeProductInfo(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'BindGridView()
        Dim productID As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtAltprodID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim productNumber As String = DirectCast(gvProductNumber.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtAltprodNum"), TextBox).Text
        Dim oDs As New DataSet()
        oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        oDs.Tables.Add("product")
        oDs.Tables("product").Columns.Add("productID")
        oDs.Tables("product").Columns.Add("productNumber")
        Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("product").NewRow
        oDr("productID") = productID
        oDr("productNumber") = productNumber
        oDs.Tables("product").Rows.Add(oDr)

        oDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
        BindGridView()
    End Sub
```